# Reuse the signed in page in multiple tests playwright

Tags: node.js, typescript, automated-tests, playwright, playwright-test

I'm new to playwright and even node.js frameworks

Currently I'm building a framework using playwright with typescript
Everything was going fine until i came to the step where i need to execute my tests sequentially using same page in th test suite as tests depends on each other

Whenever i try to run login.test script it runs first test which is login and close the browser
and open another context/page to run second test which is "do anything else"
Which is not what i want.
What i want is to execute first test then sec one using same page
So, any help with that?

`fixture.ts`

```
    loginPage:LoginPage;
  
} 

const mainPages= baseTest.extend<pages>({
    
  
    
    loginPage:async({page},use)=>{
        await use (new LoginPage(page))
    }
```

`loginPage.ts`

```
    constructor(page) {
        super(page)
       
    }
    loginPageObjects = new LoginPageObjects();
async userLogin(url,mail,password): Promise<void> {
    await webActions.navigateToURL(url);
    await webActions.setTextToElement(this.loginPageObjects.mail,mail);
    await webActions.clickElement(this.loginPageObjects.nextBtn);
   
      
}
```

`login.test.ts`

```
test.describe.serial('General test', () => {
 
 test('login',async({loginPage)=>{
   await loginPage.userLogin(userCredentials);
     
    
 });
 test('do anything else',async({login2})=>{
    
     
    await login2.clickHere(data.Btn1);

   
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's documented [here](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-auth#reuse-the-signed-in-page-in-multiple-tests).

Declare the `page` variable outside the tests, remove the `loginPage` fixture and then create an instance of login page like this:

```js
test.describe.serial('General test', () => {
    test('login', async () => {
        const loginPage = new LoginPage(page);
        await loginPage.userLogin(userCredentials);
    });

    ...
});
```

You can also declare and initialize the `loginPage` in the outer scope right after `page` and use it in multiple tests.

Comment: Is there anyway else where we can use fixtures and still can execute tests using same page?